# Run same testbench with different parameter files in VUnit

Tags: python, ghdl, vunit

I have a project with the following structure:

```
tb_top
├── run.py
└── src
    ├── tb_top.vhd
    ├── test_a
    │   ├── top_parameter.vhd
    │   ├── input.csv
    │   └── output.csv
    ├── test_b
    │   ├── top_parameter.vhd
    │   ├── input.csv
    │   └── output.csv
    └── ...
src
├── bar.vhd
├── foo.vhd
└── top.vhd
```

`top.vhd` includes `foo.vhd`, `bar.vhd` as well as `top_parameter.vhd` of each test case. In `run.py`, first the files at `src/` folder are compiled and then the `top_parameter.vhd` for each test case. All files are in the same library. When running `run.py` the following error is displayed:

```
tb_top/src/tb_top.vhd:44:20: entity "top" is obsoleted by package "top_parameter"
/usr/local/bin/ghdl: compilation error
```

Obviously, `top.vhd` should be recompiled everytime when `top_parameter.vhd` gets recompiled, but I can't figure out how to structure my `run.py`. Is there are way to compile the tests correctly, without:

1. recompiling `foo.vhd` and `bar.vhd` for each test?
2. duplicating identical files like `tb_top.vhd` and `run.py` for each test?

I'm using VUnit 4.2.0 and the current master of ghdl. If needed, I can prepare a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiled libraries can't change between test runs in VUnit. The preferred solution is to pass the parameter as top level generics instead of using a separate file.

However, I didn't want to change the file structure. So in my case, `top_parameter.vhd` and all dependent files got compiled into a separate library for each test case. To chose the correct library, an extra generic got passed to the testbench.

More details and other options can be found [here](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/issues/590).